# how to redirect to another php file after clicking on submit?

Tags: javascript, php, html

Iam trying to redirect to another php file called index2.php.
Username and password value is already set, username: sid, password: yeaoklogin.

so now when the user clicks on the button Login it will send the user to an page called index2.php.

How would I achieve this ?

Answer (score 2):

You would typically do this with the action attribute on the form

### HTML

```
<form action="index2.php" method="POST">
  <input name="username"/>
  <input name="password" type="password"/>
  <input type="submit" value="Login"/>
</form>
```

### PHP (index2.php)

```
if (isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])){
  if ($_POST['username']=='sid' && $_POST['password']=='yeaoklogin'){
     echo 'login success';
  }else{
    echo 'login failed';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following:

```
header("Location: index2.php");
```

Comment: Should be a full path, not a relative path in a header redirect.